# call ngModel with custom data type as interface

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

at my code, i've created an interface as

```
export interface IEmpresas {
  nome_fantasia : string;
  razao_social : string;
  cnpj : string;
}
```

now on my component i create a variable with data type as my interface like this:

```
...
private empresa : IEmpresas;
...
```

Im trying do this variable as model putting on my html input :

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="empresa.razao_social" id="razao_social">
```

but for someo reason, i still getting:

**' Cannot read property 'razao_social' of undefined'**

Comment: Mate, can you mark my answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The undefined error you are getting is because you have not instantiated your object.

```
 public empresa : IEmpresas={nome_fantasia:'',razao_social:'',cnpj:''};
```

**P.S.** Use `public` instead of `private`,
TypeScript `public` doesn't matter but `private` does

> **From Angular Docs**
>    All *data-bound* properties must be TypeScript `public`
>   properties. Angular never binds to a TypeScript `private` property

*Actually, it does bind to the private properties, but not in `AoT` mode*

**[Working StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yse4wa)**

Comment: never passed by my mind that i'm obligated instantiate the property. i was thinking that was automatic by angular. thanks. works very fine :D

Comment: Glad, I could help Can you make it as correct answer :)

Answer (score 1):

You should init your variable : `private empresa : IEmpresas = {};`.